# Script to open webpage, edit input field and submit form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, vtiger, vtigercrm

In our CRM system there was an error that not all values in an Invoice were properly saved in the database.

But, if we open one Invoice, edit anything and 'Save' the invoice, it will correctly be pushed into the database.
As there are hundreds of invoices where we need to do this, I dont want to manually do this but write a script that automates this.
Also I dont want to change the entries in the database directly, because it could lead to issues with calculations.
Our CRM is running on an Ubuntu Server.

What I need now:
How do I write a script which:
1) Queries SQL to get a list of the invoice id's that need to be fixed.
2) calls the webpage:
https://crm.com/index.php?module=Invoice&view=Edit&record=3000
where 3000 at the end is the invoice id.
3) Writes some value to the input field that was created for the Bugfixing
 
4) Submits the form

How can I persue this?
1) Is a "form" just a http post request that I can maybe give the parameter of the updated input field?
2) Can I do this with PHP/JavaScript that I just put in the root folder of the CRM system on the server and call it.

I need to know how to start with this problem and the general solution.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

- Edit the PHP code to add some JS code only if an extra parameter (like &fixInvoice=1) is present in the URL.
- That JS code would be executed when the page is fully loaded and would just send the form.
- Get the list of the invoices ids that you need to fix, and build a list of URLs with that extra parameter.
- Now, to open all those URLs you could build a simple HTML file with an iframe for each URL if the list is not big (under 100 URLs maybe). If the list is bigger you could build a HTML file with one iframe, and feed the list of URLs to a JS that would set the iframe src to the first URL, wait X seconds (it depends on how long the server takes to process the page, you should test it), feed the second one, etc.